# Passing adserver tags through Codeigniters global xss filter

Tags: codeigniter, xss

I use the latest CI version. In config.php:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

I can't change this.

I need to save adserver tags (will stored in files, not DB), which contains also Javascript. So with this setting I cant save the adservertags, CI or the input filter removes some parts of it.

My first idea was to encode the adservertag with base64 in the client and then on ther server decode it again, what dou you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a plan.

Except there is no native way to base64 encode on the client. However, a friendly fellow on Stack-O has solved this for you already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246813/183254 Be sure to share an upvote for them.

Comment: yes thx. I use this plugin so far and it works: https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64